# How to Remove Both Duplicates from a Dictionary?

Tags: python, mapreduce

I'm writing a reducer for a `MapReduce` program that is supposed to read two csv files: `all-bills.csv` and `open-bills.csv`. What I want to do is remove values in open-bills from all bills so that I can get all the paid bills.

What I have done is to add all the entries into a dictionary in my reducer. How do I remove the entries that occur twice or more than that so that I'm left with just the paid bills in my dictionary?

Comment: can you provide an example? How are you organizing the data? Are the .csv files only for one person?

Comment: Multiple people in a restaurant. For example theres 'A' who hasn't paid his bill so he appears in both all-bills.csv and open-bills.csv. If I create a dictionary such that A becomes the key, i'll have to two entries in my dictionary from both the files. If this happens, I want to delete both of them so that I am left with only those people who have paid their bills.

Comment: Is the data in your csv files organized around (unique) bill IDs? Or around customer IDs? Your naming implies that a record in csv file looks as follows: billID, custID, bill-detail-1, bill-detail-2, etc. --is it so? BTW, could it be easier to have just one csv-file, with additional column 'bill-status' that would indicate bill status 'Paid', 'Open', 'Other', ...

Comment: Around bill ID. The one csv file youre suggesting it what I want to eventually create :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{k: v for k, v in all_bills.items() if k not in open_bills}
```